# Laravel eloquent get specific user with his relations

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i am trying to get one user with his relationships. So one user form user table could have many items, so relationship is one to many.
Booth model

```
public function booths() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Booth');
}
```

User model

```
public function users() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I set foreign key from Booths table user_id is connected with Id from User table.

I try this query

```
$booth =User::findOrFail(83)->booths()->get();
```

But get all users. Also tried with with() but in that case i get all booths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
$user = User::with('booths')->findOrFail(83);
```

Comment: cool, maybe edit your post so your code shows correctly... was a bit hard to read...